80s horror movie where guy murders family with an ax then leaves through a field?
I believe movie was from the 80's as I watched it when I was a kid in elementary school which would have been in the 90's. Ive tried looking it up from what I can remember online, but sadly my memory is not for certain on anything since I was so young when I watched them. 
I believe the movie started with a guy (probably mid 20's) murdering either his parents, or some random people in a house with an ax. All I remember is this scene which after shows him walking through a field away from the house. I had believed for awhile that this movie was Warning Signs, but after watching trailers recently I am no longer sure as there is no reference to a murderer in the movie. 
I honestly dont even know if the movie is good, I just really want to know the name of it so I can stop looking it up when it randomly enters my head.
The movie I have tried looking up through google searching with the above information and have been unable to figure anything out.
Any possibilities?

Not sure if its more detailed or not, but its as best as I can do. I dont really remember anything precise enough to ask in the title.

I've taken a crack at making the title more specific.  Please revert if this is not sufficient

This is a far shot: The Shining (1980).

Good movie, though not it. If i recall correctly this is how the movie started not ended. I could be mistaken though.
